# is there anything in java like header files in C/C++

Tags: java

In C, there is this concept of header files that lets you include the header files required for most of the program in one go and so you can only import that one header file in each of your program. I find this pretty neat. Now, I have been working in JAVA for a while and afaik I cannot group together a set of imports that I require for almost every file and put them in one. Am I wrong? And is this better than putting all the required bunch in one java file.

Comment: IMHO developers most of the time are using *Organize imports* and auto-import features in their IDE, making imports management essentially invisible.

Comment: create your own library?

Comment: A library isn't gonna fix it. The Java language doesn't provide the kind of flexibility that will allow you to subvert fundamental principles like imports, short of writing your own compiler.

Answer (score 11):

There's no such thing. If you require a class from another package (that isn't in java.lang), you'll have to import. But that's practically trivial when using a proper IDE. In Eclipse or NetBeans, you're usually one key combo away from fixing your imports.

Comment: Are these classes (that you use over and over again) your own classes?  If so and they are in separate packages, you might consider putting them all in the same package.  Then, a single import will take care of it (as in `import com.ij.*;`).

Comment: Don't do that. Partition classes into packages according to proper logic. There are several approaches possible (for example, WEB4J adheres to something called "package-by-feature"). Lobbing everything together into a single package for import convenience is totally unnecessary when IDEs offer so much support and auto-complete magic. EDIT: check this for some advice on what might work -> http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205

Comment: Not my own classes. But there are a few imports that are common across multiple files like java.util.Vector, org.apache.xxx etc.

Answer (score 4):

There's no equivalent to header files in java, however you can import whole packages:

```
import mypackage.*
```

Comment: that's not the same thing at all.  Import doesn't actually bring anything into the JVM; it's just a device for saving typing.

Comment: This is discouraged, though. I'm not entirely sure why it's looked down upon, but IDEs tend to nag about it.

Comment: It's also not encouraged to include multiple headers in a sole header files and include that in all other places.

Comment: @G_H: IMO, its discouragement is a legacy from the days before IDEs. I consider this outdated and only use this style now (and have configured my IDE for it). Developers tend to write smaller classes these days too, which helps as well (i.e. fewer imports).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Wouldn't know that, I'm not a C(++) developer. But it kind of sounds icky. At SingleShot: Would make sense. It might increase the chance of naming collisions, forcing you to use canonical names, but that is still somewhat rare to come across. I have the imports collapsed in NetBeans by default, so they don't bother me.